# Running stored procedure/UDF X number of times when proc inserts rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, cursor

I've got a stored procedure that looks like:

```
create proc spInsertDrugQuestions  
@drugId int  
as  
begin  
declare @drugName varchar(50)= (select distinct drugName  
        from Drugs  
        where DrugId = @drugId)  
--class question and answer  
declare @drugClassQuestion varchar(250) =   
        'What is the drug class of your ' + @drugName          

declare @drugClassAnswer varchar(50) = (select distinct drugClass  
             from drugs  
             where drugId = @drugId)  
--dosage question and answer  
declare @drugDosageQuestion varchar(250) =   
      'What is the dosage of your '  + @drugName  

declare @drugDosageAnswer varchar(50) = (select distinct drugDosage  
           from drugs  
           where drugId = @drugId)  

--QuizQuestionTypeId is a foreign key to another table not shown
--but indicates the general type of question (dosage, class, etc.)
insert into DrugQuestions(DrugId,DrugQuestion,CorrectAnswer,QuizQuestionTypeId)  
values  (@drugId,@drugClassQuestion,@drugClassAnswer,3)  
  ,(@drugId,@drugDosageQuestion,@drugDosageAnswer,1)  
end
```

This stored procedure is for an end user who enters in new information into the `Drugs` table and the corresponding questions in the `DrugQuestions` table will be added.  For the time being, however, I need to be able to run this stored procedure for every `DrugId` that currently exists in the `Drugs` table.  I think the best way to do this is use a `UDF` and `CROSS APPLY` joining on a numbers table that will have every `DrugId`.  However, I'm not too familiar with UDFs and the following attempt

```
create function fnInsertDrugQuestions(@drugId int)
returns int --think can't be right, but it didn't give me any read squigglies
as begin
declare @drugName varchar(50)= (select distinct drugName  
        from Drugs  
        where DrugId = @drugId)  
--class question and answer  
declare @drugClassQuestion varchar(250) =   
        'What is the drug class of your ' + @drugName          

declare @drugClassAnswer varchar(50) = (select distinct drugClass  
             from drugs  
             where drugId = @drugId)  
--dosage question and answer  
declare @drugDosageQuestion varchar(250) =   
      'What is the dosage of your '  + @drugName  

declare @drugDosageAnswer varchar(50) = (select distinct drugDosage  
           from drugs  
           where drugId = @drugId)  
insert into DrugQuestions(DrugId,DrugQuestion,CorrectAnswer,QuizQuestionTypeId)  
values  (@drugId,@drugClassQuestion,@drugClassAnswer,3)  
  ,(@drugId,@drugDosageQuestion,@drugDosageAnswer,1)  

end
```

gives me the errors:

```
Msg 443, Level 16, State 15, Procedure fnInsertDrugQuestions, Line 21
Invalid use of a side-effecting operator 'INSERT' within a function.
Msg 455, Level 16, State 2, Procedure fnInsertDrugQuestions, Line 21
The last statement included within a function must be a return statement.
```

I need to know a couple things:

```
1.) Is it possible to insert data like this using a UDF?
2.) Is it possible to used `CROSS APPLY` with a stored procedure?
3.) Do I really want to loop through all the `DrugId`s to do this?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No - Use a stored procedure if you want to insert data, you can
   still return data from a stored procedure if required.
2. Yes - You can use CROSS APPLY in a stored procedure.
3. No - You could just use the following to insert all current drugs,
   especially if it is being done as a one off:

---

```
INSERT DrugQuestions (DrugId, DrugQuestion, CorrectAnswer, QuizQuestionTypeId)
SELECT  DrugID,
        DrugQuestion = t.Question + drugs.DrugName,
        CorrectAnswer = t.Answer,
        t.QuizQuestionTypeId
FROM    drugs
        CROSS APPLY
        (   VALUES
                ('What is the drug class of your ', drugs.DrugClass, 3),
                ('What is the dosages of your ', drugs.drugDosage, 1)
        ) t (Question, Answer, QuizQuestionTypeId);
```

If you are bulk inserting drugs i.e. multiple drugs at a time from a user, rather than repeating the same function for each new drug, you can use the output clause to collect new drugIDs then combine with the above to add new questions:

```
DECLARE @NewDrugIDs TABLE (ID INT NOT NULL);
INSERT Drugs (DrugName, DrugDosage, DrugClass, ...)
OUTPUT inserted.drugID INTO @NewDrugIDs
SELECT/VALUES   ...

INSERT DrugQuestions (DrugId, DrugQuestion, CorrectAnswer, QuizQuestionTypeId)
SELECT  DrugID,
        DrugQuestion = t.Question + drugs.DrugName,
        CorrectAnswer = t.Answer,
        t.QuizQuestionTypeId
FROM    drugs
        CROSS APPLY
        (   VALUES
                ('What is the drug class of your ', drugs.DrugClass, 3),
                ('What is the dosages of your ', drugs.drugDosage, 1)
        ) t (Question, Answer, QuizQuestionTypeId)
WHERE   drugs.DrugID IN (SELECT ID FROM @NewDrugIDs);
```

Comment: i did not even know about the `OUTPUT`..`INTO` clause.  Awesome, always great to learn something new to make your life easier.